# Any point in having BizTalk Server Developer Edition without proper Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk

Microsoft provides a [free Developer Edition of BizTalk Server](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/developer.aspx). I'd like to do some BizTalk development to get insights into what I think is an interesting bit of enterprise technology. Now, [BizTalk Server systems requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/system-requirements.aspx) list a full version of Visual Studio as a prerequisite for the BizTalk Developer Tools:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 provides a development environment for
>   rapidly building applications that target any device and integrate
>   with any platform. This is required for the Developer Tools and SDK
>   component of both BizTalk Server and BizTalk RFID. The Developer Tools
>   and SDK component cannot be installed on Visual Studio 2010 Express
>   Editions.

There's a video [Example of an Orchestration (BizTalk)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLEvSF0Bpzw) that gives you an idea of what the Dev Tools for VS look like.

Is it possible to do BizTalk development without the Dev Tools? Does it make sense? Is there any point in installing BizTalk Server on a developer machine without a non-Express version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to install the BizTalk server runtime, which would allow you to dig around in the BizTalk Server Administration console. You can use that to create ports that send and receive messages, without the need for Visual Studio.

However, that is about as far as you can go without Visual Studio. You'll need it to compile schemas, build maps to transform data, and create orchestrations.

Comment: Thank you. It sounds like administration and configuration of out-of-the-box functionality are possible, but not development, which is what I'm most interested in.

Comment: You can install Visual Studio 2012 Professional and use it for 30 days without entering a product key. After installing VS, when you are prompted to enter a product key, enter a dummy value such as all zeros; VS will complain about the value but you can close the window and start using VS. After Biztalk is also installed you can create Biztalk projects.